# Zurb Foundation Orbit: lazy-loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, zurb-foundation, lazy-loading

I'm very happy with [orbit](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html), the image slider of [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), but it doesn't support **lazy-loading** out of the box. I know [Interchange](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/interchange.html), but that's not what I'm looking for.

I found [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/foundation-framework-/AA_T7vVj920) with a [fork](https://gist.github.com/mohhasbias/5496600) as a solution. I'd like to **avoid a fork** and prefer to extend the code, to keep my files **upgradeable**.

There's no [event](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/orbit.html#events) like `on('before-init.fndtn.orbit')`.

Does anyone know, how to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes - it's configurable with css so it should be compatible with Zurb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), because there was no proper way to use orbit with lazy loading out of the box, the time i asked this question.

A few months later I'm still happy with slick.

```
<img data-lazy="img/lazyfonz1.png"/>

$('.lazy').slick({
  lazyLoad: 'ondemand',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It probably depends on your exact use case, but I was able to do it like this:

- In your template remove `data-orbit` from the orbit container, to prevent it from auto-initializing:
  `<div class="orbit" role="region" aria-label="my gallery">`
- Use [jQuery.lazy()](http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/) or a similar library to lazy load the images. I used `data-src`: `<img class="orbit-image" data-src="/path/to/image.jpg" alt="description">`
- When the images are lazy loaded (e.g. in a callback), re-add the `data-orbit` attribute, and re-initialize foundation for the orbit container. `$gallery.find('.orbit').attr('data-orbit', '').foundation();`